# Best practice to increment version on Nightly build on .NET projects

Tags: .net, versioning

I work in a team where we have over 90 .NET projects. Each nightly build reads a Version.xml file where we have the file version X.X.X.X and increments it to X.X.X.X+1 then on each build we us this version in AssemblyInfo.cs. When build is done the Version.xml is comitted to Subversion.

The last part creates one line log when looking at the top level trunk which is disturbing the  view.

Which practice are you using on .NET projects ?

/donnib

Comment: It's interesting that i am the only one having this issue, maybe we are doing something different than others....hmm

Answer (score 0):

I know that answering a question 10 years after might seem a bit weird.. :) but I have a similar issue of mixing good *human-made* semantic versioning versions (see https://semver.org/) with numbers that are automatically incremented by a nightly builds CI job.

And I saw this blog article which explains quite well what the problem is and suggests to keep a manual approach to versioning instead of *subcontracting* versioning to an automatic job: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/12/10/semantic-versioning-with-continuous-deployment/

Addition: There is also a special version of semantic versioning that has been designed to take into account CI jobs versions: see https://csemver.org/

Hope it'll help people with similar questions.